How to use positional field names with Miller `cut` verb
I want to use Miller cli to cut records based on numbered position, not specific field name.
For example I want only the 2 field (t), I've tried the following but no dice.
echo s=green,t=red,a=3,b=4 | mlr cut -f '$[[2]]'

I guess the Positional field name in the docs are for put and filter verbs only.

Hi, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78913573/757714

Yes positional field name are for put and filter verbs only, then you must use put and control structures.
In example, if you want the fourth field you can run
echo s=green,t=red,a=3,b=4 | mlr put -q '
  @i = 0;
  for (k, v in $*) {
    @i += 1;
    if (@i == 4) {
      emit {k: v};
      break;
    }
  }
'

to have b=4.

Hei thanks yea this works fine and versatile!

There's no much point in using an accumulator like @i for a local variable, just i is enough ;-)

 echo s=green,t=red,a=3,b=4 | mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output cut -f 2


For cut we do not need $[[]]. (-f 2 will do for a usual csv.)
Have to deal with headerlessness. Miller Reference

Hope this helps.

This is a nice work around, but aborruso answer is preferable as more complete and versatile, thank you for your answer!

The constructs $[[N]] (key at position N) and $[[[N]]] (value at postion N) can help; you only have to replace $* with a new map:
echo s=green,t=red,a=3,b=4 |

mlr put '$* = {$[[2]]: $[[[2]]]}'

t=red


With the -s option of the put verb you can define an accumulator externally, so you don't even need to hardcode the field number in the DSL code:
echo s=green,t=red,a=3,b=4 |

mlr put -s i=3 '$* = {$[[@i]]: $[[[@i]]]}'

a=3


And if you need to extract multiple fields by position then the code is a bit more complex; here I'm extracting the fields #2 and #3 which I define externally:
cat <<'EOF' |
s=green,t=red,a=3,b=4
u=gray,v=blue,c=5,d=6
EOF

mlr put -s f=2,3 '
  begin { @f = splita(@f, ","); }
  $* = mapselect($*, apply(@f, func(i) { return $[[i]]; }));
'

t=red,a=3
v=blue,c=5

